# Is there a way to open two source files simultaneously in Qt Creator 2.3?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I'm using dual monitor, so I would love to drag my current source view to another window so that I can compare it with others. Unfortunately, I couldn't find an option that let me do this in Qt creator 2.3. I wonder is there a way to do this in Qt Creator? My current version is 2.3.1.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can split the text editor in "Window" > "Split side by side". Then just make the Qt Creator application spread over your two screens, and manually move the split bar to the center.

Comment: is there a way to scroll both windows?

Answer (score 0):

```
Press Ctrl+E, then press 2 to get split view.  
Press Ctrl+E, then press 3 to get side-by-side split view.

To go to the other split, use Ctrl+E, then press O (alphabet O)  
Delete current split - Ctrl+E then press 0 (number zero)  
Delete all splits instead of current - Ctrl+E then press 1
```

For more keyboard shortcuts, see https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-keyboard-shortcuts.html